# Can one run a PutItem in DynamoDB in Golang without using a struct?

Tags: json, go, struct, amazon-dynamodb

All of AWS' examples involve using a struct to organize and optimize your data prior to doing anything with DynamoDB. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/dynamo-example-create-table-item.html

For my project I am getting a JSON string back from a third party API. I actually want to store the entire JSON object in DynamoDB but I can't determine if it's possible without a struct. Because I'm working with a third party API, I can't guarantee what fields I will get, or if the fields will change in the future. Can this be done? In NodeJS it's quite easy, but I understand that Go is statically typed so it may just not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will always need a struct for your item static key and/or range. The JSON can go in another field of type `map`, which can contain items or nested maps. Then let `attributevalue.MarshalMap` transform the whole struct into a [DynamoDB map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes.Document.Map).

```
type Record struct {
    ID   string
    JSON map[string]interface{}
}

r := Record{
    ID:   "ABC123",
    JSON: map[string]interface{}{
        "Parent": "aa",
        "Children": map[string]interface{}{
            "Child1": "foo",
            "Child2": "bar",
        },
    },
}

av, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(r)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal Record, %w", err)
}

_, err = client.PutItem(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
    TableName: aws.String(myTableName),
    Item:      av,
})
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to put Record, %w", err)
}
```

example partly taken from https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue